# PHP cURL function is not working on specific site

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am new to `PHP` and trying to use `cURL` function to fetch the view of a page, but I am unable to fetch for particularly *www.zomato.com*, while all other websites are working fine using this code.

```
<?php 
    set_time_limit(0);
    function getSslPage($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mypro/cacert.pem"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 44455); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo  curl_error($ch);
        echo  curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result; 
    }
    ECHO getcwd();
    $a=getSslPage("https://www.zomato.com/ncr/open-house-connaught-place-new-delhi/");
    echo ($a);
?>
```

I get error no.- 056 when trying to use this code.

Comment: `cURL` error 56 is "error receiving network data".

Comment: what is the solution for this? this error comes only on this specific website.

Comment: Do you mean your code works for other pages _inside that domain_ or just for other, independent pages in other domains?

Comment: none of the pages are working of this domain. other domains are working fine.

Comment: Then most likely that page implements some form of protection against your scraping attempts. That is very likely, since they try to protect their content. Your action is most likely violating the terms of usage, so illegal, unless you have their consent, in which case you can ask them for assistance.

Comment: is there any other way to fetch the data of that domain? without their assistance?

Comment: Well, technically that obviously has to be possible, since a browser can fetch it. So there is some difference between the request a browser sends and your cURL request. You will have to examine that difference and try to minimize it. You can use a network sniffer to monitor and compare both requests. But as said: without their consent this probably is illegal.